# Opening an A frame environment on mobile phone?

Tags: javascript, android, html, aframe, virtual-reality

I have a VR game I created and I am trying to access it on a mobile phone.

I have heard something about github.io and accesing A frame related things , but I am not sure how this works.In any case, I just want a method to access my game on a mobile phone. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to just Host it, and it will work from the users browser.  Or are you after a way of bundling as a native app?

Comment: Not sure what bundling as a native app means but i created a server (via python) with the files and assets required to launch the aframe environment. However I am not sure how to access the server and hence open the aframe environment on my phone.

Comment: Navigate the browser on your mobile phone to the server running python.  Eg. if say your IP address of your server is  192.168.1.22  and the port your python script is running on is 3000, type `http://192.168.1.22:3000` into the browser on the mobile,  you might need to set some firewall rules etc on your server machine, alternatively host your app on a hosting provider,  they might even handle HTTPS for you, as the HTTP protocol if not `localhost` can often be crippled.

Comment: Oh, you mentioned gitHub, yes you can host simple website on there too, have a look here -> https://pages.github.com/